# Fetch data from JSON file, save as objects and fetch data with a key-value

Tags: java, arrays, json, key-value, json-simple

I have a JSON file

```
{
    "measurements": [
      {
        "time": "100416",
        "temp": "7.64",
      },
      {
        "time": "110416",
        "temp": " 7.76 ",
      },
      {
        "time": "120416",
        "temp": " 7.86 ",
      }
    ]
}
```

and I need to save the values as class objects( or Hashmap) with a key value of "time". Then while typing "time" for example: 120416 It will print the temp for that time. I'm using Netbeans.

This is where I'm so far. I can print an Array:

```
public class Weathers {
    private static final String filePath = "C:\\measurements.json";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {

            FileReader reader = new FileReader(filePath);
            JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
            JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonParser.parse(reader);

            JSONArray JArray = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("measurements");
            for (int i =0;i <JArray.size();i++)
            {
            System.out.println(JArray.get(i));
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParseException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NullPointerException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 Map<Integer, Double> map = new HashMap<Integer, Double>();
        for (int i =0;i <JArray.size();i++)
        {
            map.put(JArray.get(i).getInt("time"),JArray.get(i).getDouble("temp"));
             System.out.println(JArray.get(i));
        }
```

Comment: Where do I get the .jar file able to import getInt and getDouble?

Comment: which json library are you using? Almost all json libraries has this support. for example, I'm using org.json.simple.JSONObject, it has really simple usage about getting int, double from json object.

Comment: I have json-simple.jar. Everything else works, but not getting int or double.

Comment: write jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getInt("key")